# Ho to calculate geometric mean as a Catch per Unit effort variable

Tags: r, dplyr, count, mean, data-manipulation

I am trying to calculate the arithmetic and geometric mean of fish catch data for a variety of different species. Therefore I am trying to get means that represent the number of fish caught per net.

My issue is that not all species were caught during each catch event and data was not recorded on the absence of species. Therefore I want to make sure the arithmetic and geometric mean reflect all events instead of just the events they were captured in.

To recap, I am looking to get calculate the arithmetic mean and geometric mean of the number of fish caught for each species. Here is some example code:

```r
count <- c(10,13,15,18, 2,5,10,4,23,13)
net_set <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4)
species <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B")
data <- data.frame(fishCount = fish_count, netSet = net_set, Species = species)
```

The arithmetic mean is simple to compute but I keep getting geometric means larger than arithmetic means which I realize is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want to do first is to add 0 for all species and nets that don't appear, but other species and nets appear, then calculate the mean for each species.

One way to tackle the first problem is the turn your dataset into wide format, and fill all missing values as 0.  This works because each net will get a row and each species will get a column, so if a combination of a row/column doesn't have a value, this can be filled with 0.  Then turning the data back into long format, we can keep these filled values.

However, since there could be multiple species in a group, there will be duplicates of species net combinations, so we will have to remove those duplicates.

```r
count <- c(10,13,15,18, 2,5,10,4,23,13)
net_set <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4)
species <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B")
data <- data.frame(fishCount = count, netSet = net_set, Species = species)

library(tidyverse)
data_cleaned <- data %>% 
  mutate(temp = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(netSet, temp), 
    values_from = fishCount, 
    names_from = Species,
    values_fill = 0
  ) %>% 
  select(-temp) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(netSet), names_to = 'Species', values_to = 'fishCount')
```

The code above will count duplicates however.  For example B, 1 has three values: 0, 0, 15.  To clean these up, we want to remove groups where the value is 0, but the sum is larger than 0.

```r
data_cleaned <- data_cleaned %>%
  distinct %>%
  group_by(Species, netSet) %>% 
  filter(!(fishCount == 0 & sum(fishCount) > 0))

data_cleaned
#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#> # Groups:   Species, netSet [12]
#>    netSet Species fishCount
#>     <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1      1 A              10
#>  2      1 C               0
#>  3      1 A              13
#>  4      1 B              15
#>  5      2 A              18
#>  6      2 B               2
#>  7      2 C               5
#>  8      2 C              10
#>  9      3 A               4
#> 10      3 B               0
#> 11      3 C              23
#> 12      4 A               0
#> 13      4 B              13
#> 14      4 C               0
```

The next step would be to calculate the mean for each species, which we can use the handy function `group_by()` followed by `summarise()`.

```r
data_cleaned %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(fishCount),
            geo_mean = exp(mean(log(fishCount[fishCount > 0])))
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Species   avg geo_mean
#>   <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A         9       9.84
#> 2 B         7.5     7.31
#> 3 C         7.6    10.5
```

I don't know much about geometric means, but the reason the geometric means are larger is because we are excluding 0 since I don't think we can calculate geometric mean for 0 values, whereas if we exclude 0 for both means, then the mean is larger than the geometric mean:

```r
data_cleaned %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(fishCount[fishCount>0]),
            geo_mean = exp(mean(log(fishCount[fishCount > 0])))
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Species   avg geo_mean
#>   <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A        11.2     9.84
#> 2 B        10       7.31
#> 3 C        12.7    10.5
```

Comment: What would happen if you used the actual number of samples as the argument to the radicle?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  What are you referring to when you say radicle? If you're talking about in the pivot_wider, i think you could switch the species and net arguments and get the same result

Comment: oh wait, I see a mistake in my answer that you might have pointed out - i'll work on fixing it

Comment: When you draw a “root sign” that’s actually called a radicle. The number above the sharp down-up stroke is the degree of the root.

Comment: The bit where I use exp(mean(log(x))) is the same as prod(x)^(1/n) because of log properties.  It is easier to use so I don't have to specify the number of samples - the mean does it for me.  But one could definitely write it the other way where you specify the number of samples in the radicle

Comment: My thought was to include the count of the zeroes in ‘n’

Comment: FWIW it's "radical" (as in "root"), not "radicle" (from Wikipedia, a "radicle" is "the first part of a seedling (a growing plant embryo) to emerge from the seed during the process of germination.").  If zero occurs at *any* point in a sample, then the geometric mean of that sample is indeed negative infinity (or undefined, depending on how picky you're being ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the bipartite lesson. If you have a series with some zeroes, wouldn't it seem natural to omit them from the product value but keep the count of values at the original? Seems like you would get something like a Poisson mean.